# Why do I get the error unhandeled exception when trying to open my inputstream in Android studio? (code posted in description)

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I am trying to read a file as inputstream to fill in the file with additional data. This data is then supposed to be sent over to a second activity which unwraps the data and displays it on the screen. **this is my code**

```
package com.example.daniel.finalproject;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.res.AssetManager;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.renderscript.ScriptGroup;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;

import com.google.android.gms.appindexing.Action;
import com.google.android.gms.appindexing.AppIndex;
import com.google.android.gms.appindexing.Thing;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Secondactivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.secondactivity);

    }

    public void Proceed(View view) {
        AssetManager am = getAssets();
        InputStream is = am.open("madlibsimple.txt");
        Story story = new Story(is);
        EditText editText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.word);
        String text;
        story.toString();
        while (!story.isFilledIn()) {

            story.read(is);
            story.getNextPlaceholder();
            text = editText.getText().toString();
            story.fillInPlaceholder(text);
            }

        Intent intent = new Intent(this,   Thirdactivity.class).putExtra("story",story);
        startActivity(intent);

        }

    }
```

However this line: `InputStream is = am.open("madlibsimple.txt");`
returns the error. *madlibsimple.txt* is in the assetsfolder, but I
don't know what goes wrong. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: code in 2nd activity:

        String in = getIntent().getStringExtra("story");
        TextView textView (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView);
        textView.append(in);

Comment: I'm still not sure, what you want to do. Do you want to send data from one Activity to another?

Answer (score 0):

`open(String file)` can throw an error (i expect `IOException`) that you have to catch with an

```
try {
    AssetManager am = getAssets();
    InputStream is = am.open("madlibsimple.txt");
    Story story = new Story(is);
    EditText editText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.word);
    String text;
    story.toString();
    while (!story.isFilledIn()) {

        story.read(is);
        story.getNextPlaceholder();
        text = editText.getText().toString();
        story.fillInPlaceholder(text);
        }

    Intent intent = new Intent(this,   Thirdactivity.class).putExtra("story",story);
    startActivity(intent);
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStacktrace();
}
```

statement.

This whole topic is not about what goes wrong, but what COULD go wrong

For more information on the topic of exceptions and errorhandling you can click [here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_exceptions.htm)

Comment: I believe the error is solved, but I still get a curly line under madlipsimple.txt saying that i have made a typo which i have not. I think this is the reason why my program crashes at the secondactivity. This is pretty much my secondactivity code
        <code>String in = getIntent().getStringExtra("story");
        TextView textView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView);
        textView.append(in);

Comment: sorry, I made a mistake. you have to include everything in your Proceed function.

Comment: But that doesn't change the fact that you have to catch the exception that could be thrown by getAssets().open(file);

Comment: Stil persisting that the file name is not correct though

Comment: Do you ever create the file, and write data to it? Is the file name at every occastion the same?